# WPF Display empty text/ null as default value for bound control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, default-value

I have a TextBox that bound to a double-type property and a Combobox that bound to an enum-type property. Under some conditions, I have to set the TextBox and Selected Item of Combobox to empty string.

I figured that if I create a custom class that have the default value and override the ToString() method, I can do that. Something like

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault {get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => IsDefault ?  string.Empty : Value.ToString();    
}
```

and then Bind the TextBox to property with my custom class-type.

However, that is too much of a work when I have to deal with multiple type properties. Is there better way to do it, more "WPF style" that I can apply to multiple data type which does not have a special default value?

Comment: You can write a `IValueConverter`

Comment: That does not solve my problem since the Converter needs an input - my properties. However I can not set a default value to that properties so that the converter knows that it is handling the default and it should return empty string. As in my example, I can set double.Nan as default and the text box works fine, but the enum value for the combobox does not since that enum type does not have special value, nor can I set it to null. What I want is a specific solution for my example and a general one too.

Comment: What about `TargetNullValue` or `FallbackValue`? Actually first one sounds perfect for you, but you need to update the xaml

Comment: I'm not sure a bout TargetNullvalue, but I do believe FallBackValue does not help at all.  FallBackValue just used to set a default value to the control, but the core problem is that I can not determine the default value for the bound property because I can not set null to a double/ enum datatype. The Nullable datatype did solve my problem, for now. I take a look at the TargetNullValue and let you know later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I can use nullable data type instead of the original data type and it does solve my problem. Extra call to GetValueOrDefault() and some cast is needed though.

This way does not require the custom class for every datatype that existed in my code and it is quite generic, too. Still looking for elegant way of WPF. Ideas and contribution is much appreciated.